# Using grep for listing files by owner/read perms

Tags: regex, linux, bash

The rest of my bash script works, just having trouble using grep. On each file I am using the following command:

```
ls -l $filepath | grep "^.r..r..r.*${2}$"
```

How can I properly use the second argument in the regular expression? What I am trying to do is print the file if it can be read by anyone and the owner is who is passed by the second argument.

Using:

```
ls -l $filepath | grep "^.r..r..r"
```

Will print the information successfully based on the read permissions. What I am trying to do is print based on... [read permission][any characters in between][ending with the owner's name]

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem with your attempt is the final `$` which anchors the search to the end of the line, which is the end of the file name, not the owner field. A better solution would replace `grep` with Awk instead, which has built-in support for examining only specific fields. But actually [don't use `ls` for this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), or really in scripts at all.

Unfortuntately, the `stat` command's options are not entirely portable, but for Linux, try

```sh
case $(stat -c %a:%u "$filepath") in
    [4-7][4-7][4-7]:"$2") ls -l "$filepath";;
esac
```

or maybe more portably

```sh
find "$filepath" -user "$2" -perm /444 -ls
```

Sadly, the `-perm /444` predicate is not entirely portable, either.

Paradoxically, the *de facto* most portable replacement for `stat` to get a file's permissions might actually be

```sh
perl -le '@s = stat($ARGV[0]); printf "%03o\n", $s[2]' "$filepath"
```

The `stat` call returns a list of fields; if you want the owner, too, the numeric UID is in `$s[4]` and  `getpwuid($s[4])` gets the user name.

Comment: `find` seems like the one that was specially designed for that.

Comment: I would actually go primarily with `stat`; the purpose of `find` is to search for files matching specific criteria more generally, so using it on a single named file is weird.

Comment: One problem, I was directed to use ls to list file information then pipe it to grep. It is a homework to practice regex.  The algorithm that I did not include makes an array, given a passed directory, where each element is a subdirectory and file within it. I could include that code too if it would help. I just need to figure out the current setup for that regex above, where it follows the format [read perms][ignore between][ownername]

Comment: Probably the only problem with that is the final `$` which anchors the search to the end of the line, which is the end of the file name, not the owner field. A better solution would use Awk. Going forward, probably mention in your question if you have artificial constraints, like howework instructions.